# how can I count the pixel of each row?

Tags: matlab

I have an image as binary I want to count each row white pixels and keep them in an array and then compare them together. could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Given a matrix `A` the sum of every row can be obtained by using `sum(A)`

Comment: actually sum(A)give the sum of each column ;) I did this method before but it is not working

Comment: sorry, use sum(A,2).
The second parameter is the dimension on which to sum.